# Why do i get a syntax error at or near "alter"?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I am using PostgreSQL and just got this error. Here is my code

```
  alter table seatbooking 
  add foreign key (BookingId) 
  references FlightBooking(BookingId);
```

All I get is:

> ERROR: syntax error at or near "alter"

Can someone help me? thanks.

Comment: your statement looks ok. try first Ctrl+C and then run it

Comment: It doesn't do anything

Comment: ah, you not using `psql` - what is your client?

Comment: How exactly are you issuing the statement? Is it in the psql command line? Is it from a GUI app? Is it code inside your app?

Comment: I am just writing and running it from the SQL editor, from PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Code looks correct so it's probably a copy paste error in your client. Just try to retype the entire thing in a new window. (don't copy paste)

Comment: You are right, if write it in a new window, it works.

Comment: Ok, bad news, after I retype all of my code into a new window, the same error stays there, what should I do now?

Comment: Do you have an ";" add the end of each line? In case you have multiple statements this is required.